# How can I make a function which takes the arguments of one of it's arguments in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

This is probably impossible, but I'm trying anyways.  I'd like to make a function roughly like this pseudo code:

```
function modifyClass<MOD_ME extends SomeClass>(
  baseClass: typeof MOD_ME, 
  args: ...MOD_ME.arguments
): MOD_ME {
  args[1] = "second arg is always this string";
  return new baseClass(...args);
}
```

The objective of this is to be able to do something roughly similar to decorators, without all the prototype stuff.  I want to be able to have type-checking while wrapping a class constructor.   A function call like so:

```
import MyClass from "./MyClass"
import modifyClass from "./modifyClass"

const moddedClassInstance = modifyClass(MyClass, myClassArg1, myClassArg2);
```

The biggest issue here which I'm running into is getting the types for the arguments of whatever the baseClass is.  Is it possible to so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in 3.0 using conditional types and [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897)

```
type CtorArgumentTypes<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any> = T extends new (...args: infer A) => any ? A : []
function modifyClass<MOD_ME extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(
    baseClass: MOD_ME, 
    ...args: CtorArgumentTypes<MOD_ME>
): InstanceType<MOD_ME> {
    return new baseClass(...args);
}

class Test {
    constructor(public n: number, public s: string) {

    }
}

let o = modifyClass(Test, 10, ""); //ok
let o2 = modifyClass(Test, "", ""); // error
```